# specifying dimensions of document to match size of text / math environment

Tags: environments, dimensions, latexit

How set the dimensions of the space allocated to an environment? e.g. if I wanted a single equation $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ to be centred in an area exactly 5cm high and 10cm long, how might I do this?

I am using LaTexIt to create .jpgs for use online and need to be able to set the overall proportions of the resulting image, but the output seems to default to the exact size of the content. I was hoping I could code in some space around it in such a way as to be able to specify the dimensions of the final output.

I've been searching for over an hour & tried various boxes to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `standalone`; run with `pdflatex -shell-escape`

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\newcommand{\sizedmath}[3]{%
  \parbox[t][#2][s]{#1}{%
    \centering
    \vspace*{\fill}
    $\displaystyle#3$\par
    \vspace*{\fill}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% \sizedmath{<width>}{<height>}{<formula>}

\sizedmath{4cm}{2cm}{x^2+y^2=R^2}

\end{document}
```

Here is the produced PNG file that you can download for looking at its properties.

[image]

The PDF file (from which the PNG is produced) info window says

[image]

Comment: I really am in awe of you: both your knowledge & willingness to help. Thank you very much!

Comment: For anyone else making use of this: the command doesn't work in LaTexIt; however, it effectively removes the need for LaTexIt for this particular application.